# How to open ssh://username@hostname link

Tags: gnome, ssh, gconf

I want to open link like "ssh://username@hostname" with ssh.
I think xdg-open can help me(xdg-open ssh://username@hostname), but I don't know how.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I could gather, you have to register the protocol in the gconf:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/enabled true
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/command 'gnome-terminal -e "%s"'
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/needs_terminal false
```

([source](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/))

I can't get it to register ssh in chromium though. Haven't tried with firefox, but [these instructions](http://www.roberthorvick.com/2009/07/03/adding-a-custom-protocol-to-firefox-for-easy-erlang-docs/) should help.

Comment: Just a note: This does not work in Gnome 3. I tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the ssh link on the command line by using `ssh username@hostname` (I think you know this already) if you want to access it via nautilus in gnome then you can minimise all windows and do [ctrl]+L which will open a dialog. Type in your url `ssh://username@hostname` and click open.

This should solve most of your problems. xdg-open can only open the url if the url has been mounted somewhere already. Otherwise it can't access the ssh files.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly then i think you want to open such link in gui mode. To open such links in nautilus just replace ssh with sftp

open nautilus and type sftp://user@host in address bar and press enter

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for Gnome support for `ssh://` links that we use at our work on our internal websites. I ended up making my own simple script in my home directory that could handle them.

I choose to place it in `~/bin` that I created for my local scripts, but you can choose whatever you want, of course.

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/bin
cat << 'EOF' > ~/bin/open-ssh-link.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gnome-terminal -- ssh $1
EOF
chmod +x ~/bin/open-ssh-link.sh
```

Now when you click your first `ssh://` link, you should be prompted to provide
a program to open this link. Here you enter the file just created at
`~/bin/open-ssh-link.sh`.